# DNS Forwarder only working with nslookup, browser does not open external url

Tags: internet-explorer, dns, windows-server-2012, proxy-server, nslookup

We configured a Domain Controller (Windows Server 2012), we're using DNS Forwarder to resolve external DNS request as google, yahoo, etc, but we are having a very strange problem to browse external url.

Background:

Domain Controller is located at 10.32.202.66
PC is connected in the network with DNS 10.32.202.66, the PC is able to resolve:

nslookup google.com
nslookup 74.125.21.128 (google)
Internet Explorer is able to open an internal URL
BUT the problem we have is that IE does not open external URL as www.google.com

We cannot configure a proxy server in IE, so my questions are: 
Why the DNS Forwarder is working only with nslookup
How I can configure IE in order to open external URL

Answer (score 0):

A DNS Forwarder cannot forward HTTP requests for you. You need NAT or a proxy.